# ftp_login to localhost shows authentication failed

Tags: php, authentication, ftp

I have written a snippet to connect to my localhost xampp from the server but it shows authentication failed despite the correct credentials.

I tried the script on localhost it worked but it doesn't from my server "scaledrop.net" .

```
<?php
set_time_limit(3600);
$file = '/home4/scale/public_html/admin.xls';


$ftp_server="localhost";
//set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$ftp_user_name="horrible";
$ftp_user_pass="";
// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);//print $login_result;
 $fp = fopen($file, 'w+');

 $remote_file="StockREport.xlsx";
//upload a file
if (ftp_fget($conn_id,$fp, $remote_file,  FTP_ASCII)) {
 echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";}
 else {
 echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

It gives me this warning:

> ftp_login() [function.ftp-login]: Login authentication failed in /home4/scale/public_html/trial.php on line 12

I have tried to access this account from the explorer and even the Filezilla with the same credentials and it is perfectly accessible in these.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the FTP share from the server itself, e.g. using `ftp` via `ssh`? FTP might be configured to forbid connections from `localhost`.

Comment: I assume the same FTP account exists on your scaledrop as does on your localhost?  Or are you changing the server host?  is the password actually blank?  maybe try setting it to non-blank to see it it might help.